# Carpet and Padding Type for Exercise and Floor Pressure, Seen in Hotels

Tags: flooring, carpentry, carpet, pad

I am doing exercise, light weightlifting, aerobics, and yoga on carpet.

I use exercise mat, however I noticed its not enough. What is good type of carpet and padding, that holds up to exercise pressure? I see different category types: Pad, Density, Pile and Textured, Plush, Frieze, Cable, Berber, etc. I am kind of interested in the Hotel carpeting seen in Ramada, Hilton, which stands up to heavy suitcase pressure, and rolling. Recently, my carpeting is making a squeaky sound, and padding is uneven in some places.

https://www.hgtv.com/design/remodel/interior-remodel/your-guide-to-the-different-types-of-carpet

https://www.yourflooringexperts.com/2014/03/24/carpet-101-six-basic-styles/

Comment: Are you looking to replace the carpet in the entire room, or are you looking for an "area rug" to lay out when you're exercising, then roll up & put away when you're done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google "anti-fatigue" carpet tiles, for hotel quality gym carpeting.

Here is an example (I am not endorsing this site in any way, just providing an example to get an idea of what you are looking for):

https://www.flooringinc.com/carpet/tiles/anti-fatigue.html

As far as padding goes, there is also anti-fatigue padding, but you should talk to the vendor of your anti-fatigue carpet tile for recommendations on your particular situation.